# for-loop query all rows in database. but result just show the last of row

Tags: android, database, for-loop, arraylist, row

I have 4 rows of latitude in database and I want to get all that rows of it. In `CafeDataSource` I had query it and set it to `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>`. 
When I use it in `TopActivity` in `for`loop, I can query all 4 rows. but all 4 rows just have one value of the last row. Ex, my database (1,2,3,4) but my result (4,4,4,4).

I had log(db) in `getArrCursor()` for value and it works fine.

I had log(number) in `for` loop for value but it shows me all and all are the last row.

How can I query it all and different row?

CafeDataSource

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> getArrCursor(){
    arrCursor = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> map;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+CafeDbOpenHelper.TABLE_CAFE, null);

    if(cursor != null){
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_TITLE, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_TITLE)));
            map.put(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_THUMB, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_THUMB)));
            map.put(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_LATITUDE, cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_LATITUDE)));
            map.put(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_LONGITUDE, cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_LONGITUDE)));
            Log.i("db", "" +cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_LATITUDE)));
            arrCursor.add(map);
        }
    }
    return arrCursor;
}
```

TopActivity

```
int position = arrCursor.size();
for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
    Log.i("number", "" +arrCursor.get(position -1).get(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_LATITUDE));    
    double lat = (Double) arrCursor.get(position -1).get(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_LATITUDE);
    double lng = (Double) arrCursor.get(position -1).get(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_LONGITUDE);
    LatLng latlong = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    Marker maker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlong).title((String) arrCursor.get(position -1).get(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_TITLE)));

    // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlong, 17));

    LinearLayout includeMap = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_map);
    includeMap.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Position` never changes but you are using that to get from the `Array` every time. Try instead

```
double lat = (Double) arrCursor.get(i).get(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_LATITUDE);
double lng = (Double) arrCursor.get(i).get(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_LONGITUDE);
```

**Edit**

Did you change this line

```
Marker maker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlong).title((String) arrCursor.get(position -1).get(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_TITLE)));
```

to

```
 Marker maker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlong).title((String)                
    arrCursor.get(i).get(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_TITLE)));
```

You are starting at the `i` position of your `Array` so every time you want to access that postion you will use `i`

Comment: but my map it doesn't show all the 4 marker. it just show one marker